# how to remove openssl library dependencies

Tags: linux, openssl, dependencies

when i try to execute the `Linux executable` on other fresh machine my program gives an error for dependency of `OpenSSL`.

For running my program smoothly it requires `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` preloaded.

How can i remove this dependency using make file or any other solution on `Linux`

Comment: Its up to you to decide what meets your needs. You can use [NSS](http://nss-crypto.org/), [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/), or other security library that suits you needs.

Comment: i just want to attach these dependencies with make file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you linked your executable with OpenSSL libraries dynamically. So your executable needs libcrypto.so and libssl.so. You have two ways:

1. OpenSSL is pretty widely distributed in Linux environment and most probably is pre-installed on the Linux you are running your executable on. So the problem may be in the required version of the libraries - your executable may be compiled with e.g. OpenSSL 1.0.1 and Linus has 0.9.8. Or the problem could be with the path of the libraries. In RadHat OpenSSL libraries are in /lib64 by default. So you need either to build your application with the same or compatible version of OpenSSL as present on Linux where you run or provide the correct path by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. You can link your executable static with OpenSSL libraries:

   gcc -lsome_dynamic_lib code.c libcrypto.a libssl.a

Comment: so can i simply use this line in my make file and if i am not wrong you saying that after doing the second option i will not need these two files for running my object file on other machines

Comment: Yes, if you go for the second option and make a static link with OpenSSL libraries you will not be dependent on OpenSSL .so files.

Comment: when i am attaching these lib files in the makefile. when i try to compile the code then it tries to takes all the other dynamic as static. can you tell me the path of libraries of libgcc